# How to sum first n number of entries in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, recursion, sum

I'm new to programming and learning about javascript recursion. It's my 5th day with JavaScript and following an online course.
The problem is that I need to sum up first n numbers of entries (first 3 numbers in this case) in an array.
But I'm ending up with sum of all and that also I'm not sure about.

```
var theArray = [1, 3, 8, 5, 7];

function sum(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return arr[n - 1] + sum(arr, n - 2);
    //assuming n is arr.length and n-1 is hence arr.length-1
  }
}

console.log(sum(theArray, 3));
```

What am I doing wrong?
I checked most people are solving such with reduce method or with for of loop. I didn't learn those yet in the curriculum. But I know 'for loop' but that's good if the numbers are in incremental order I guess. Please explain this problem in my level.

Comment: You missing a closing `}` at the end of your function

Comment: Step back and think about what your code does. You are saying that the sum of 0 elements is 1. Is that really the right answer, or would another number be better? :)

Comment: When you recurse, you should only subtract `1` from `n`, not `2`. The sum of the first N elements of an array is the Nth element plus the sum of the first N-1 elements. If you subtract 2, you're skipping every other element.

Comment: not sure why recursion would be needed here.

Comment: @Dominik Fixed. Thanks for spotting :)

Comment: @RobinZigmond You are right. My bad. I thought to set the base case to just anything.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm that clears up some confusion. But the curriculum was hinting ``return arr[n-1] + sum(arr, n-1); `` That is where I'm getting confused. Shouldn't it be like ``return arr[n] + sum(arr, n-1);`` ?

Comment: @epascarello That's the criteria for the given problem. I must use recursion. :)

Comment: @Bluebug: yes, it would be `return arr[n] + sum(arr, n-1);` if what you call "the nth element of the array" was `arr[n]`. But it's not. Array indices start at 0. "The first 3 elements" are elements 0, 1 and 2, not elements 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @Stef Oh right! Now I can picture it in my mind! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing something recursively, it's a good idea to think about the base condition.  It does look like that's where you started, but your logic is flawed.  `n` is the number of elements you would like to sum together.  So let's say you want to sum the first `n=3` elements of the array `[2,3,4,5,6]` and get 9.  Here are the iterations.

1. return arr[n-1] + sum(arr, n-1) // arr[2] + sum(arr, 2) === 4 + sum(arr, 2) === 4 + 5
2. return arr[n-1] + sum(arr, n-1) // arr[1] + sum(arr, 1) === 3 + sum(arr, 2) === 3 + 2
3. return arr[n-1] // arr[0] === 2 (base case when n is 1)

I didn't solve the problem for you since this is obviously a school exercise, but the point is that the base case and the recursive call that you have are both slightly off.

Comment: Right, I can visualize it now. Thanks a lot for clearing it out. And I'm not in school... I'm learning on my own while working full time :) But yes you got the point. I should figure out the rest on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Array of undetermined length, find the largest sum possible for any 3 consecutive numbers.

1. `[2,0,1,100,200,10,7,2, 300,2,1 0]` here `100,200,10 = 310` is the correct answer. Here only the combination of these 3 numbers produces the largest sum.
2. `[2,1,0,20,71 = 0+20+7 = 27` is the answer that you should return.

```js
const findMax = (numberArray) => {
let first = 0;
let second = 1;
let third = 2;
let max = 0;

    for(; third < numberArray.length; first++, second++, third++) {
    if(max < (numberArray[first] + numberArray[second] + numberArray[third])) {
        max = numberArray[first] + numberArray[second] + numberArray[third];
    }
    }
  return max;
}

console.log('Max sum of three consecutive numbers in array ===>  ',findMax([2, 0, 100, 200, 10, 7, 2, 300, 2, 10]));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here.  This raises a mostly-unrelated question, and attempts to answer it.  Please don't do this in answers to questions.  If you want to [post your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), please do do.  (You're free to answer it if you think you have a good solution.)  But don't attach it to an existing question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31149599)